# Link para visualização de anexo

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Tenho um hiperlink  para visualizar meu anexo. Meu anexo encontra-se no servidor  e o seu caminha gravado no banco de dados. Estou querendo na hora que a pessoa clicar no Hyerlink abra uma nova aba e apresentar o anexo.

Segue meu código

```
function popuplista(c) {
    popupwide("'"+ c +"'");
}

<asp:HyperLink ID="lblMensagemAnexo" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Anexo") %>'
                        Text="Clique aqui para ver o anexo" Width="250px" Visible="false" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>

lblMensagemAnexo.NavigateUrl = "javascript:popuplista('" + dt.Rows[0]["Anexo"].ToString() + "');";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marconi,
Você não precisa usar um WebControl e nem javascript para fazer isso. Ao invés tente algo mais simples como:

```
<a href='<%#Eval("Anexo")%>' download target="_blank">Clique aqui para ver o anexo</a>
```

- download força o browser a baixar o conteúdo do link. (não funciona no IE)
- target é usado como fallback

Answer (score 1):

Um tempo atrás estava com esse problema também.

Após pesquisar, não consegui achar um jeito de fazer isso através do ASP.NET.

O método que consegui fazer para resolver o problema, foi adicionar um evento ao click do `LinkButton`:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lblMensagemAnexo" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Anexo") %>' Text="Clique aqui para ver o anexo" Width="250px" Visible="false"  OnClick="lblMensagemAnexo_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

E então no Evento, usar o JavaScript para abrir uma nova aba.

```
protected void lblMensagemAnexo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string url= btn.CommandArgument;
    Response.Write("<script>window.open('" +url+"','_blank');</script>");
}
```

Só ressaltando, foi a maneira que encontrei para resolver o problema.

Comment: Coloquei coisa errada, troca o NavigateUrl pelo CommandArgument.

Comment: Funciona, porém não irá abrir em uma nova aba. Porque o target, não funciona no hyperlink.

Comment: Desculpe @Marconi, me confundi. Achei que fosse LinkButton, aí sim teria que utilizar esse procedimento. Para um HyperLink, basta usar o Target.